# Date pattrern format of 2021-02-22T00:00:00

Tags: java, date, jodatime

could somebody tell which is this date format ?

```
2019-01-22T00:00:00
```

I througth it is

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss
```

But i am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: T
I am using DateTimeFormatter from org.joda.time.format

Comment: Yes, `T` isn't a pattern specifier in the same way that `YYYY` etc are, so you need to put it in quotes. But you should look *very carefully* at the casing of everything. I suspect you want `dd` rather than `DD`, and `HH` instead of `hh`. (You might want to consider the difference between `yyyy` and `YYYY`, too.)

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

Comment: I think you ought to put the "T" like `'T'` if  I correctly recall. You can try you pattern(s) with any [java formatter](http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko could you please move to asnwer ?

Comment: Year should and days should be written in lowercase and I think your is pattern missing colons between T, eg: 
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
Here some articles about it: 
https://help.gooddata.com/cloudconnect/manual/date-and-time-format.html
https://www.journaldev.com/17899/java-simpledateformat-java-date-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format string is

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
```

where

```
yyyy - years in four digit form
MM   - Months in 2 digit form
dd   - days in 2 digit form
'T'  - Letter T (note escapement '...')
HH   - Hours in 24 hour form, leading zero is mandatory
mm   - miniutes with leading zero 
ss   - seconds with leading zero
```

Please, consult [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for details

Answer (score 3):

### No formatter needed

You don’t need a formatter for that one and hence no format pattern string.

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;

    String s = "2019-01-22T00:00:00";
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(s);
    System.out.println(ldt);
```

Output:

> 2019-01-22T00:00:00.000

The format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

If you had wanted a format pattern string, maybe for stricter validation, you would need:

1. Lower case `dd`.
2. `'T'` in single quotes.
3. Upper case `HH`.

While I prefer lower case `yyyy` for year, upper case `YYYY` for year of era works too with Joda-Time.